# Testing reCAPTCHA locally. Validates on mac, but not on windows

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm testing reCAPTCHA locally on both OS. The keys generated are for domain(s) localhost and 127.0.0.1.

On my mac the SAME EXACT files works flawlessly. I copied said files to my windows computer and my response ALWAYS returns NULL.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test</title>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone"><br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="PUBLIC_KEY"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP (SERVER)

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $privatekey = "SECRET_KEY";
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => $privatekey,
        'response' => $captcha,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );

    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

$jsonResponse = json_decode($response);

if ($jsonResponse->success === true) {
    echo '<br><p>CAPTCHA was completed successfully!</p><br>';
}
else {
   echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
}

?>
```

Appreciate any help provided.

Comment: What is the expected result? And windows/osx probably shouldn't be tagged here.

Comment: Removed windows/osx tags. Just curious to know why I would have mixed  results on different OS, and if there may be anything wrong with my code.

Comment: That may just be a configuration issue.

Comment: Thank you! I uploaded to a test server and it's working perfect.